# UIButton in Swift with two images

Tags: swift, uibutton, customization

I'm trying to make a UIButton that has a UIImage on either side (left and right) of the button's title. Ideally, the images would be pinned to the left and right sides of the button, and the title would be centered, but I can live with the images being right next to the title label I suppose. I have been able to add one image, which appears right before the title, but how would I add a second?

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old question but since no code was provided and someone asked for it I figured I would share my solution for this.

What I did was create a new class which subclasses a UIButton. I made sure that you can see all the changes you do instantly in your interface builder as well. So you can just drag in a UIButton. Specify the class to your own class and it will allow you to set the images and see it being drawn instantly

Here is what I did to achieve this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class AddProfilePictureView: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var leftHandImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            leftHandImage = leftHandImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            setupImages()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var rightHandImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            rightHandImage = rightHandImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            setupImages()
        }
    }

    func setupImages() {
        if let leftImage = leftHandImage {
            self.setImage(leftImage, for: .normal)
            self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: self.frame.width - (self.imageView?.frame.width)!)
        }

        if let rightImage = rightHandImage {
            let rightImageView = UIImageView(image: rightImage)
            rightImageView.tintColor = COLOR_BLUE

            let height = self.frame.height * 0.2
            let width = height
            let xPos = self.frame.width - width
            let yPos = (self.frame.height - height) / 2

            rightImageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: width, height: height)
            self.addSubview(rightImageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break it into two buttons within a collection view- it's very flexible and can work great for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIImageView` with an image to the button by `addSubview` and another to the button by `setImage`, it can be adjusted with `titleEdgeInsets` and `imageEdgeInsets`.

if you need a code sample – let me know.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey I know you wrote this last year but think you could show some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5, XCode 11.6**

Please use the below code in your extension or in a custom UIButton class. I have used the below code in my custom class. The function will set left or right image respectively and align the text.

```
/// Sets a left and right image for a button
/// - Parameters:
///   - right: right image
///   - left: left image
func setImages(right: UIImage? = nil, left: UIImage? = nil) {
    if let leftImage = left, right == nil {
        setImage(leftImage, for: .normal)
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: (bounds.width - 35), bottom: 5, right: 5)
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: (imageView?.frame.width)!)
        contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    }
    if let rightImage = right, left == nil {
        setImage(rightImage, for: .normal)
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: (bounds.width - 35))
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: (imageView?.frame.width)!, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
    }

    if let rightImage = right, let leftImage = left {
        setImage(rightImage, for: .normal)
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: (bounds.width - 35))
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: (imageView?.frame.width)!, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        contentHorizontalAlignment = .left

        let leftImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: bounds.maxX - 30,
                                                      y: (titleLabel?.bounds.midY)! - 5,
                                                      width: 20,
                                                      height: frame.height - 10))
        leftImageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        leftImageView.image = leftImage
        leftImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        leftImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
       addSubview(leftImageView)
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

1. vegaButton.setImage(right: myImage) // for right image
2. vegaButton.setImage(left: myImage) // for left image
3. vegaButton.setImage(right: myImage, left: myImage) // for both images.