# How can I add two images (one at the left and one on the right side) in a button in Xcode programaticly? I need also a title of a button

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, swiftui-button

```
func setupButtonUI() {
if let detailsImage = UIImage(named: "detalji_icon") {
    setImage(detailsImage, for: .normal)
    contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    contentVerticalAlignment = .center
 
}

if let arrowImage = UIImage(named: "posalji_zahtev_black_icon") {
    setImage(arrowImage, for: .normal)
    contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
    contentVerticalAlignment = .center
}
```

}/*this is one of the things I tried, but whit this I get only the second image and its set in the center not right and the left image is hot even there*/

Comment: So what have you tried and what are you struggeling with?

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code there so everything is formatted correctly.

Comment: I know it can be hard as new user but please try to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @burnsi sorry the edit question took some time. I edited now. And thanks for the link for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton has only one imageView, you can create custom button like in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112735/13628690

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This didn't work in my case. I found at the end the best solution. I m explaining in the comment below

Answer (score 0):

Found the next solution: Made a custom UIView and added two images and label as a subview of customView. Did the constraints programaticly. Just added  UITapGestureRecognizer (addGestureRecognizer) at the entire view and its all elements are clickable. The design and functionality are satisfied.